# Undefined reference to functions in C++

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, undefined

I keep getting an error with `RangeCheck`, `read`, `prntword`. The errors are:

```
undefined reference to RangeCheck(short, short, short)

undefined reference to read(short*, bool)

undefined reference to prntword(short)
```

I tried to change where I placed the functions (above main, in main), but I've no idea what to do to fix the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define READ  10
#define WRITE 11
#define LOAD  20
#define STORE 21
#define ADD   30
#define SUBTRACT 31
#define DIVIDE 32
#define MULTIPLY 33
#define BRANCH 40
#define BRANCHNEG 41
#define BRANCHZERO 42
#define HALT  43
#define CELLS 100
#define RANGE 9999
#define SENTINEL -1

#define DEBUG 0

short RangeCheck(short word, short min, short max);
char* prntword(short word);
bool read(short *data, bool check);

int main()
{

    bool error = false;
    char *word, OperationCode, Operand;
    short memory[CELLS], InstructionRegister;
    int counter, Accumulator;
    Accumulator = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < CELLS; i++) {
        memory[i] = 0;
    }

    for (counter = 0; !error; counter++); {
        counter = RangeCheck(counter, 0, CELLS - 1);
        InstructionRegister = memory[counter];
        OperationCode = InstructionRegister / 100;
        Operand = InstructionRegister % 100;
    } 

    switch(OperationCode) {
        case READ:
            read(&memory[Operand], false);
            break;
        case WRITE:
            printf("%s\n", word = prntword(memory[Operand]));
            break;
        case LOAD:
            Accumulator = memory[Operand];
            break;
        case STORE:
            memory[Operand] = RangeCheck(Accumulator, -RANGE, RANGE);
            break;
        case ADD:
            Accumulator += memory[Operand];
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            Accumulator -= memory[Operand];
            break; 
        case DIVIDE:
            Accumulator /= memory[Operand];
            break;
        case MULTIPLY:
            Accumulator *= memory[Operand];
            break;
        case BRANCH:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your **function declarations** before `main` but I do not see any **function definitions** (i.e., they are undefined). Hint: The definition is where the implementation of the function exists.

Comment: You don't define the functions you call.

Comment: By the way, depending on platform it might be a bad idea to call one of your functions `read`. It is, after all, a POSIX system call with just that name. And if you're programming in C++ (not that there is any C++-specific code in your program), then why did you add the C tag? Please don't spam with tags.

Comment: That's not valid C. And format the code properly.

Comment: Take a look at [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)  It is a C++ question and answer, but a lot of what it says applies to C too.

Comment: Incidentally, note the superfluous semicolon in `for (counter = 0; !error; counter++); {
counter = RangeCheck(counter, 0, CELLS - 1);` — the one that is the empty body of the for loop and the statement block that follows the loop.  GCC 6.3.0 pointed it out in no uncertain terms: ```ur23.c:41:5: error: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
     for (counter = 0; !error; counter++); {
     ^~~
ur23.c:41:43: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘fo’
     for (counter = 0; !error; counter++); {```.

Comment: @Olaf: the only major sin as C code was the absence of `<stdbool.h>`; otherwise, the code is basically C code.  I agree the title has a reference to CPP which is misleading; the issue is not with the C PreProcessor, and it might be intended to be C++, but then why was the question tagged C?  'Tis mysterious — carelessness or confusion on the part of the OP, no doubt.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Probably because so many think `c` and `c++` are the *same thing*...

Comment: @JamesAdkison: It may be, and the confusion isn't helped by the Microsoft C development environment, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: According to the history, the question was originally tagged C++ **and** C. Reading the "CPP" in the title as C++ instead of the more common "C PrePreocessor" and considering the lack of `stdbool.h`, it sounds evident OP compiles as C++. I agree this is C-**style**, though and OP should make up his mind. Until then, I'd say it should be read as bad C++. (and when has some MS tool ever been helpful? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf: … and, I suppose the type-safe linkage errors (like `undefined reference to read(short*, bool)`) are indicative that a C++ compiler/linker is in use.  It means that the 'what is an undefined reference' question is a perfectly good 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
short RangeCheck(short word, short min, short max);
char* prntword(short word);
bool read(short *data, bool check);
```

with

```
short RangeCheck(short word, short min, short max){return 1;}
char* prntword(short word){return 0;}
bool read(short *data, bool check){return 0;}
```

and it should compile for you (however it may not work as you expect)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your own functions you must declare and define them (a definition alone can satisfy both).

> no idea what to do to fix the error

You need to define your function (i.e., provide its implementation).

[Example](http://ideone.com/zI485n):

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(); // My function declaration

int main()
{
    foo(); // To use this function it must be declared and defined

    return 0;
}

// The function definition
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared and referenced these 3 functions but not defined. You need to provide implementation of all these 3 functions.